# Appbar scrolls the background Image up without decreasing the overall toolbar size

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to use the Material Design Library to create a toolbar that has a big background Image. The toolbar is followed by a ScrollView . On Scrolling , my expectation is that the toolbar will slowly get reduced to its min height while the rest of the ScrollView expands to fill up the area . Initially when the screen renders it looks like this [image: initialView] . On scrolling the image shortens but the scrollview does not expand . It looks like this on scroll [image: On Scroll]
Any idea why this might be happening ?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
android:id="@+id/draw_insets_frame_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"><android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   app:layout_behavior=
       "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/card_view_post"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
       card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
       card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
       android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       style="@style/CardView.Light">
       <!--Has other Views inside it -->
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView></android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView><!--App bar starts --><android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="0dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I need the CollapsingToolbarLayout. The code is pasted below, in case someone runs into the same problem

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMargin="100dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.example.xyzreader.ui.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```